# How to combine two get_users() array?

Tags: search, user-meta, wp-user-query

The $q1 and $q2 are working well individually.

```
if (!empty($search_term)) {

        $q1 = get_users(array(
            'fields' => 'all',
            'role' => 'contact',
            'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*',
        ));

        $q2 = get_users(array(
            'fields' => 'all',
            'role' => 'contact',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'first_name',
                    'value'   => $search_term,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'last_name',
                    'value'   => $search_term,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'location',
                    'value' => $search_term ,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        ));

        $all_contacts = array_merge( $q1, $q2 );
        //$all_contacts = $q1;

    }

    $contacts_array = array();

    if (count($all_contacts) > 0 ){
        
        foreach ($all_contacts as $index => $contact) {
            $contacts_array[] = array(
                "id" => $contact->ID,
                "name" => $contact->display_name,
                "email" => $contact->user_email,
                "phone" => $contact->phone_number,
                "country" => $contact->location,
                "website" => $contact->user_url,
            );
        }
    }

    return $contacts_array;
```

How can I merge them together for results?

Comment: You don't have to always have The One Query. Having multiple queries is perfectly acceptable and sometimes having two queries is even quicker for the database than one. So, combining these results with `array_merge` would be my suggestion.

Comment: I have tried to with array_merge. There is no luck so far.

Comment: Can you show us your `array_merge()` attempt?

Comment: `get_users` returns an array, so you should be able to combine them with `array_merge`. It should be this: `$results = array_merge( $q1, $q2 );`

Comment: @TonyDjukic I updated the code. And I think you can get my attempt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** to clarify, the answer to

> How can I merge them together for results?

Is that you really can't, not without a lot of custom SQL and using filters. The complexity of going that route far outweighs any perceived benefits and wouldn't be very future-proof. I'd recommend using the solution below and putting it all into a method that you can call to get what you need.

**Original Answer**

I tested this locally and was able to get two sets of results - from there, I passed them through a callback in `array_filter` to remove the duplicate entries:

```php
$q1 = get_users(array(
    'fields' => 'all',
    'role'   => 'contact',
    'search' => '*'.esc_attr( $search_term ).'*',
));

$q2 = get_users(array(
    'fields' => 'all',
    'role'   => 'contact',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'first_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'last_name',
            'value'   => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'location',
            'value' => $search_term ,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));

$results = array_merge( $q1, $q2 );
$results = array_filter( $results, function( $user ) {
    static $found_users = [];

    if ( in_array( $user->ID, $found_users, true ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $found_users[] = $user->ID;
    return true;
} );
```

The `static` array is persisted over each call to the closure, allowing the code to keep track of which users have already been processed. If a user's ID is in the `$found_users` array, we `return false` which removes the current element from the array.